# Git commit message on linux terminal

Tags: linux, git, terminal

I am trying to learn how to write a git commit message on a linux terminal.

I am presented with the following options after I write my commit message.

Which is the first one I am supposed to choose?

```
> ^G Get Help  ^O Write Out ^W Where Is  ^K Cut Text  ^J Justify   ^C Cur Pos
^X Exit      ^R Read File ^\ Replace   ^U Uncut Text^T To Spell  ^_ Go To Line
```

If I hit "write out" I get another list of options that I don't understand.

```
File Name to Write:$T_EDITMSG                                                   
^G Get Help     M-D DOS Format  M-A Append      M-B Backup File
^C Cancel       M-M Mac Format  M-P Prepend     ^T To Files
```

Comment: Avoid using an editor at all, simply use the `-m` (or `-am`) option and type your message between quotes and press `[Enter]` and you are done. (e.g. `git commit -m 'Your commit message here.'` then just press `[Enter]`) See both good answers below for configuring the default editor if you go that route. (learn/use `vim` - you can lean the basics in 5 minutes and it will be on just about every Linux system you touch -- well worth the time)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because git pick up **nano** as its default terminal editor, if you are not familiar with nano, you can config git to use another one.

The easiest way to write a git commit message in terminal is to use the *-m* option:

```
> git commit -m "your commit message"
```

But if you don't specify the *-m* option, git will bring you to an editor depends on the following rules

- Git config option *core.editor*, local config goes first, then the global.

  - Local: *git config core.editor vim*, config resides in file $YOUR_REPO/.git/config
  - Global: *git config --global core.editor vim*, config resides in file $HOME/.gitconfig

  Please refer to [Git Configuration](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration) for details.
- Environment variables $EDITOR or $VISUAL

  - export EDITOR=`which vim`
  - export VSUAL=`which emacs`

  This is also the settings used by other tools when it needs an editor.

Answer (score 1):

When you just type `git commit` it will open your default text editor, **nano** in your case. You should type your message and hit enter after ^O.

To commit without opening a text editor:

```
git commit -m 'Your commit message here'
```

If you want to change your default editor to something else, say **vim**, you can do it as follows:

```
git config --global core.editor "vim"
```

Comment: But using ^O takes me to a second set of options that I don't understand. what does M-D mean?

Comment: All you need is to hit Enter at that moment, doesn't it close the editor? If it doesn't, then ^X to exit.

Comment: @ScottF -- you may be missing the point. You can ***either*** use the `-m` option (or `-am`) and type your message between quotes and hit `[Enter]` to complete the commit, ***or*** you can omit the `-m` and the default editor (e.g. the `--global core.editor`) will be opened and you type your commit message there, save and quit and the commit will be completed at that point.

Answer (score 0):

Also helpful from [GentooWiki](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Nano/Basics_Guide):
In nano's help texts the Ctrl is represented by a caret (^), so Ctrl + W is shown as ^W, and so on. The Alt key is represented by an M (from "Meta"), so Alt + W is shown as M-W.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing OP uses WSL or is new to linux. I am using a Ubuntu kernel in VS code via the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL, as before). There typing `git commit` opens a nano editor to save the commit. At least on Windows, the command to save the commit is `CTRL + S`. I don't think that option appears in the editor, but it worked for me.